# Narrowing return type by the type of message

Tags: typescript

Here's the code:

```js
type Message =
  | {
      type: 'TYPE_1';
      payload: { someValue: number };
      response: { foo: string };
    }
  | {
      type: 'TYPE_2';
      payload: null;
      response: number;
    };

type DistributivePick<T, K extends keyof T> = T extends T ? Pick<T, K> : never;

type NarrowReturnType<T> = ......

function onMessage<T extends Message>(
  message: DistributivePick<T, 'type' | 'payload'>
): NarrowReturnType<T> {
  switch(message.type) {
    case 'TYPE_1':
      // message.payload should be { someValue: number }
      useSomeValue(message.payload.someValue);
      // Must return { foo: string }

    case 'TYPE_2':
      // message.payload should be null
      // Must return number
  }
}
```

I want the return type to be `{ foo: string }` if the type of message is `'TYPE_1'`. The `onMessage` function won't be execute by myself but a node module. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use square bracket notation:

```js
type Message =
    | {
        type: 'TYPE_1';
        payload: { someValue: number };
        response: { foo: string };
    }
    | {
        type: 'TYPE_2';
        payload: null;
        response: number;
    };

type NarrowReturnType<T extends Message> = T['response']

function onMessage<T extends Message>(message: T): NarrowReturnType<T> {
    switch (message.type) {
        case 'TYPE_1':
        // Must return { foo: string }
    }
}

const result = onMessage({ type: 'TYPE_1', payload: { someValue: 42 }, response: { foo: 'foo' } }) // {foo: stirng}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried this method and this is not totally what I expected. I can return number if the type of message is 'TYPE_1' , but I want it to only return { foo: string }.

Comment: @MattPeng AFAIK, this is known issue in TS. In order to do this, you should declare a separate function for each `case`. This talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXzIZZDq2hE might be interesting for you